# How to plot, where each row in a matrix is a line inte plot in R

Tags: r, matrix, plot, row, line

I have a data frame that I would like to plot. I want each row to be plotted as a line, but when I do it says that my margins are too large. I have tried to do a for loop, but I'm new to R so it doesn't work. Can somebody please help me?

My frame is much larger, it's 67x135, but it looks something like this:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5   
85 16 13 82 72  
30 71 14 51 43  
13 63 42 37 99
```

Comment: You really want to plot 67 lines? That won't be a good plot.

Comment: points would work as well! I guess you're right, that would not look very good

Comment: The human eye/brain can't really distinguish 67 colors or symbols or linetypes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
DF <- read.table(text="V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
85 16 13 82 72
30 71 14 51 43
13 63 42 37 99", header = TRUE)

matplot(t(DF), type = "l")
```